# Get Core Data Entity relatives with a generic function

Tags: swift, generics, core-data, swift-protocols

I'm designing a data manager for my Core Data model and I'd like to create a generic function to fetch relatives of a class.

I’ve created a protocol allowing to build managers for each data type. In this protocol I already defined two associated types T and K and several simple functions. Now I’m stuck with a class relatives fetching method — I need to indicate somehow that T has K relatives. I’ve tried in vain to create some protocol indicating this relationship thru mutual properties, so both classes could conform to this protocol. Any idea, is it even possible?

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

protocol DataManager {

    associatedtype T: NSManagedObject, NSFetchRequestResult
    associatedtype K: NSManagedObject, NSFetchRequestResult // Relative

    static var sharedInstance: Self { get }

    static func getAll(sorted: [NSSortDescriptor]?, context: NSManagedObjectContext) -> [T]?
    static func insert(item: T)
    static func update(item: T)
    static func clean()
    static func deleteById(id: String)

    // Relatives
    static func getRelatives(by: T) -> [K]?
    static func get(byRelative: K) -> [T]?
}

extension DataManager {

    static func getAll(sorted: [NSSortDescriptor]?, context: NSManagedObjectContext) -> [T]? {

        guard let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<T> = T.fetchRequest() as? NSFetchRequest<T> else { return nil }
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = sorted

        var results: [T]? = nil

        do {
            results = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
        } catch {
            assert(false, error.localizedDescription)
        } //TODO: Handle Errors

        return results
    }
}


protocol Identifiable {
    typealias Identity = String
    var id: Identity? { get }
}


extension DataManager where Self.T: Identifiable {

    static func get(by id: T.Identity, context: NSManagedObjectContext) -> T? {

        guard let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<T> = T.fetchRequest() as? NSFetchRequest<T> else { return nil }

        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K == %@", "id", id)

        var rawResults: [T]? = nil

        do {
            rawResults = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
        } catch {
            assert(false, error.localizedDescription)
        } //TODO: Handle Errors


        if let result = rawResults?.first {
            return result }
        else { return nil }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I've created one solution.
We can identify all relations with a particular class:

```
let relationships = T.entity().relationships(forDestination: K.entity())
```

It allows us to find all IDs of an item for each relationship (we can have many relationships for the same relative Entity):

```
let relativesIDs = item.objectIDs(forRelationshipNamed: relationship.name)
```

So, we can use these IDs to fetch records from another class.

```
static func getRelatives(of item: T, context:NSManagedObjectContext) -> [K]? {

    guard let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<K> = K.fetchRequest() as? NSFetchRequest<K> else { return nil }
    fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 100

    var results: [K]? = nil

    var resultSet: Set<K> = [] // doesn't allow duplicates

    let relationships = T.entity().relationships(forDestination: K.entity())

    for relationship in relationships {

        let relativesIDs = item.objectIDs(forRelationshipNamed: relationship.name)
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "self IN %@", relativesIDs)
        fetchRequest.predicate = predicate

        var batchResults: [K] = []

        do {
            batchResults = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
        } catch {
            assert(false, error.localizedDescription)
        } //TODO: Handle Errors

        if batchResults.count > 0 { resultSet = resultSet.union(Set(batchResults)) }
    }

    if resultSet.count > 0 { results = Array(resultSet) }

    return results
}
```

I'm not sure that this is the most elegant solution, but it works :-)